# How can I run an analysis of variance with one independent variable and multiple dependent variables?

Tags: r, regression, anova, manova

From my limited statistical knowledge, I could use MANOVA if I had multiple independent variables (x1, x2...xn). What can I do (specifically in R) with one "x" variable and multiple "y" groups? I'm trying to see if there is any relationship between the y's with respect to their regression with x. I've already set up a loop that computes bivariate, piecewise linear regressions between each pair (x-y1, x-y2, ... x-yn), but that does not include any analysis of variation between the y variables. Does anybody know how I might do this (in a statistically sound manner, of course) in R? My data looks like this:

```
x         y1       y2      y3      y4      y5
4.19    5.51    19.76   50.00   19.36   54.07
8.60    10.16   33.01   82.99   38.48   44.95
8.03    7.82    31.29   79.05   40.12   59.18
6.64    8.99    27.13   69.13   30.44   59.02
7.03    8.22    25.29   74.45   36.02   50.88
1.50    5.90    10.69   22.88   10.34   34.50
4.36    7.61    19.27   44.47   20.06   24.62
7.17    8.30    26.72   68.68   31.61   20.16
2.68    5.61    14.25   37.07   15.20   67.75
7.91    7.75    30.93   82.01   38.62   65.36
3.74    5.24    16.42   40.17   17.54   15.19
```

Comment: You are confused. You would do a MANOVA if you have multiple *dependent* variables. If you have multiple independent variables, but only one dependent, you have a univariate problem and can use ANOVA.

Comment: @Roland Even if my independent variable, X, is numeric and doesn't have multiple levels/classes?

Comment: No, then you would do *something else*. What depends on the question you want to answer. My comment was intended to clarify your confusion regarding what is a multivariate and what is a univariate problem.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your response. What I want to answer is this: are any of the y variables related to each other as they relate to their relationship with x?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please improve the question body and give a lot more details and background.

Comment: For example, do you want to compare the slopes and/or the intercepts of the 5 regression lines?

Answer (score 2):

While what question you are trying to answer is unclear, I think you are trying to do  canonical correlation analysis (CCA), which attempts to explain a set of dependent variables (DVs) with a set of independent variables (IVs). This technique creates a linear combination of the IVs such that will account for the maximum variance of another linear combination of the DVs. Your case is special in that you have only 1 IV.

In R, you can do it in different ways:

#### Approach 1

```
manova(cbind(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5) ~ x, data=your_df)
```

#### Approach 2

```
library(CCA)
X <- cbind(your_df$x) ## cbind necessary to make
Y <- cbind(your_df$x) ## X and Y matrices
matcor(X, Y)
```

You interpret CCA results in a way similar to interpreting MANOVA results. For more information see [this tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/canonical.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately the linked tutorial `http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/canonical.htm` is not available any more (Nov 2021).